# Diagonal cascading elements and 90º borders (cause-and-effect diagram like) for fishbone list using HTML, CSS and/or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I organized some divs and paragraphs to create six different lists, all of them connected to a single arrow.
I was already able to create something that looks like a fishbone diagram, as you guys can see in the example below:

[image]

The gray (`bg-secondary` class) divs are dynamically added. Six divs have two blue borders inside a `col` (to simulate a 90º separator between them)

What I am really struggling to achieve now is the diagonal borders and cascading lists that looks like this:
[image]

The second image was poorly edited inside Paint, but the difference is that:
Instead of 90º borders, I have a diagonal one, simulating a 45º separator. Besides that, I also have the lists indented (the margin increases according to the number of items).

I have no idea of how I can achieve the 45º borders. The fact that I added those margin-right styles also made the divs smaller. What would you guys suggest?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <style>
            .arrow {
                width:100%;
            }
            .line {
                margin-top:14px;
                width:97%;
                background:#23468c;
                height:10px;
                float:left;
            }
            .point {    
                width: 3%;
                height: 0; 
                border-top: 20px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
                border-left: 30px solid #23468c;
                float:right;
            }

            .m-top-half-border {
                border-top: 8px solid;
                border-right: 8px solid;
                border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #23468c 70%, transparent 30%) 30% 1;
            }

            .m-bottom-half-border {
                border-bottom: 8px solid;
                border-right: 8px solid;
                border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #23468c 70%, transparent 30%) 30% 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 m-top-half-border" >
                                <h4 class="text-center">Materials</h4>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 140px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 70px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 m-top-half-border" >
                                <h4 class="text-center">Method</h4>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 280px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 210px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 140px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 70px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 m-top-half-border" >
                                <h4 class="text-center">Man Power</h4>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 210px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 140px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 70px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- ./col-md-11 -->
        </div><!-- ./row -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="white-space: nowrap;">    
                <div class="arrow">
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <div class="point"></div>
                </div><!-- ./arrow -->
            </div><!-- ./col-md-12 -->
        </div><!-- ./row -->


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 m-bottom-half-border" >
                                <h4 class="text-center">Machine</h4>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 70px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 140px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 210px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 280px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 350px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 420px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 m-bottom-half-border" >
                                <h4 class="text-center">Mother Nature</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 m-bottom-half-border" >
                                <h4 class="text-center">Measurement</h4>
                                <p>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 70px;" class="bg-secondary">
                                        <div contenteditable="true" class="btn-lg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- ./col-md-11 -->
        </div><!-- ./row -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding ::before to place a diagonal line and ::after to hide the specific part diagonally.

If you add this to CSS:

```css
.m-top-half-border {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.m-top-half-border::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid #23468c;
  height: 100%;
  right: 77px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
}
.m-top-half-border::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 191px;
  right: -97px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
}

.m-bottom-half-border {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.m-bottom-half-border::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid #23468c;
  height: 100%;
  right: 104px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
}
.m-bottom-half-border::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 198px;
  right: -76px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could you find out how to do it?

I think giving a full solution is a bit of work, but if that helps, I used the code you provided to create a starting point for you to continue the coding.

```css
.m-bottom-half-border {
  position: relative; /* Makes the content relative to use the ::after */
}

/* Use ::after to avoid create new HTML elements */
.m-bottom-half-border::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0; /* Right and top to keep your line to the right */
    height: 150%;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(150%); /* Here you create the rotation of 45 degrees and move to the right to avoid this crashes the content */
    transform-origin: top; /* This is to keep it centered while rotating */
    border: 4px solid red;
    background: red;
    border-bottom: 8px solid;
    border-right: 8px solid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Alvin. It was almost what I needed, @Aijit's solution complemented with the rectangles size being adjusted automatically.